# Sampling keyboard input at a certain rate in C++

Tags: c++, keyboard, ubuntu-18.04, stdin, ros

What I want to do is **sampling the keyboard input at a certain rate (e.g. 10-20 Hz)**. I use a while loop that read from stdin (I use read because I want to read asynchronously, e.i. I don't want to press enter every time) and then I have a pause before a new cycle starts to keep the sampling frequency stable.

The user press left/right arrow to give a command (to a robot). If nothing is pressed, the output is 0.

The problem is that, **during the pause, the stdin buffer is written (I suppose), and so the read will return an old input**. The final result is that the output is delayed. So if I press left the output immediately change to 1, but when I release it takes some seconds to return to 0. I want to remove this delay.

My aim is to sample just the more recent key pressed, in order to synchronize user input and output command without delays. Is there a way? Thank you in advance.

This is the method I'm using:

```
    void key_reader::keyLoop()
{
    char c;
    bool dirty = false;
    int read_flag;

// get the console in raw mode
tcgetattr(kfd, &cooked);
memcpy(&raw, &cooked, sizeof(struct termios));
raw.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
// Setting a new line, then end of file
raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;
raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
tcsetattr(kfd, TCSANOW, &raw);

//FD_ZERO(&set);     /* clear the set */
//FD_SET(kfd, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */

//timeout.tv_sec = 0;
//timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

if (fcntl(kfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
{
    perror("fcntl:"); // an error accured
    exit(-1);
}

puts("Reading from keyboard");
puts("---------------------------");
puts("Use arrow keys to move the turtle.");

ros::Rate r(10);
while (ros::ok())
{
    
    read_flag = read(kfd, &c, 1);
    switch (read_flag)
    {
    case -1:

        // case -1: is empty and errono
        // set EAGAIN
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
        {
            //no input yet
            direction = 0;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            perror("read:");
            exit(2);
        }

    // case 0 means all bytes are read and EOF(end of conv.)
    case 0:

        //no input yet
        direction = 0;
        break;

    default:

        ROS_DEBUG("value: 0x%02X\n", c);

        switch (c)
        {
        case KEYCODE_L:
            ROS_DEBUG("LEFT");
            direction = 1;
            dirty = true;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_R:
            ROS_DEBUG("RIGHT");
            direction = -1;
            dirty = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    continuos_input::input_command cmd;
    cmd.type = "Keyboard";
    cmd.command = direction;
    cmd.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    key_pub.publish(cmd);
    r.sleep();
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the issue is with your subscriber rather than publisher. I can see that you have used rate to limit the publishing rate to 10Hz. Do confirm the publishing rate using Topic Monitor in rqt. Also setting a lower queue size for the publisher might help. Can't give a more definitive answer without referring to your subscriber node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I haven't a subscriber, I just listen the topic with `rostopic echo`.

Comment: Oh then its probably just a delay in the terminal output. Do implement a subcriber and see how it reacts